# Why npm install command reruns again and again in node app?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, package.json

I'm going through a weird situation. I got a node application in macOS Sierra 10.12.3. I also got the following information:

node -v prints v8.4.0
npm -v prints 5.3.0

The package.json file:

```
    {
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "description": "My Node App",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "install": "npm install",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=6"
  },
  "author": "blackjack",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.5.8"
  }
}
```

When I run "npm install" in order to install dependencies, those dependencies are installed, however, "npm install" reruns. Actually, it never stops running again and again.

Look this:

```
pathfinder:myapp blackjack$ npm install --loglevel verbose
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
npm verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
npm verb cli   'install',
npm verb cli   '--loglevel',
npm verb cli   'verbose' ]
npm info using npm@5.3.0
npm info using node@v8.4.0
npm verb npm-session 0695436488c367c7
npm info lifecycle myapp@1.0.1~preinstall: myapp@1.0.1
npm verb correctMkdir /Users/blackjack/.npm/_locks correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb lock using /Users/blackjack/.npm/_locks/staging-e02d0e92bf103f5a.lock for /Users/blackjack/dev/web/myapp/node_modules/.staging
npm verb unlock done using /Users/blackjack/.npm/_locks/staging-e02d0e92bf103f5a.lock for /Users/blackjack/dev/web/myapp/node_modules/.staging
npm info linkStuff myapp@1.0.1
npm verb linkBins myapp@1.0.1
npm verb linkMans myapp@1.0.1
npm info lifecycle myapp@1.0.1~install: myapp@1.0.1

> myapp@1.0.1 install /Users/blackjack/dev/web/myapp
> npm install

npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'install' ]
npm info using npm@5.3.0
npm info using node@v8.4.0
npm verb npm-session aeb46163714f97fa
npm info lifecycle myapp@1.0.1~preinstall: myapp@1.0.1
npm verb correctMkdir /Users/blackjack/.npm/_locks correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb lock using /Users/blackjack/.npm/_locks/staging-e02d0e92bf103f5a.lock for /Users/blackjack/dev/web/myapp/node_modules/.staging
npm verb unlock done using /Users/blackjack/.npm/_locks/staging-e02d0e92bf103f5a.lock for /Users/blackjack/dev/web/myapp/node_modules/.staging
npm info linkStuff myapp@1.0.1
npm verb linkBins myapp@1.0.1
npm verb linkMans myapp@1.0.1
npm info lifecycle myapp@1.0.1~install: myapp@1.0.1

> myapp@1.0.1 install /Users/blackjack/dev/web/myapp
> npm install

^C
```

It never prints "OK" to tell it worked as expected. 
The application runs ok after "node app.js" command. However, it prevents ths installation in AWS Beanstalk. I couldn't see any error printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you talk about angular-seed git repository, there is `"prestart":"npm-install"` in package.json. You can remove this in order to prevent it from running repeatedly. If it is there in package file, then even if you run `"npm start"` command, it will run `"npm install"` also.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `"install": "npm install",` from your package.json.

As you can see in [the document](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts), npm runs a command specified here after the package is installed. So specifying `npm install` here will run `npm install` forever.